# Child fragment's onResume() not getting called

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a parent `fragment`. I have a `tabView` with two tabs in the parent `fragment`. The first `tab` has a `mapView` and the send tab has a `recycler listView`. When I resume the parent fragment, `onResume()` of the parent is getting called but not the `onResume()` of the `fragments` in the `tabView`. How do I get this to work?

My parent fragment look like this

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
            @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.route_tab_fragment, null);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Injector.component().inject(this);

        setupViewPager(viewPager);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }

    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        adapter.addFragment(new RouteFragment(), "Map");
        adapter.addFragment(new RouteListFragment(), "List");
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
```

Comment: what you want to do?

Comment: When I resume the parent fragment, I want the fragments within the tab also to load. Currently, this happens only onCreate. How do I get this to work when I resume the parent fragment?

Comment: did u solved it?